# create table in phoenix from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-phoenix

Hi I need to create a table in Phoenix from a spark job . I have tried 2 ways below but none of them work, seems this is still not supported.

1) Dataframe.write still requires that the tables exists previously

```
df.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode("overwrite").option("table", schemaName.toUpperCase + "." + tableName.toUpperCase  ).option("zkUrl", hbaseQuorum).save()
```

2) if we connect to phoenix thru JDBC, and try to execute the CREATE statemnt, then we get a parsing error (same create works in phoenix)

```
var ddlCode="create table test (mykey integer not null primary key, mycolumn varchar) "

val driver = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver"
val jdbcConnProps = new Properties()
jdbcConnProps.setProperty("driver", driver);
val jdbcConnString = "jdbc:phoenix:hostname:2181/hbase-unsecure"
sqlContext.read.jdbc(jdbcConnString, ddlCode, jdbcConnProps)
```

**error:**
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "create" at line 1, column 15.

Anyone with similar challenges that managed to do it differently?

Comment: have you found any way out for above issue ? I was also looking for same.

Answer (score 1):

i have finally worked in a solution for this. Basically i think was wrong by trying to use SQLContext read method for this. I think this method is designed just to "read" data sources. The way to workaournd it has been basically to open a standard JDBC connection against Phoenix:

```
var ddlCode="create table test (mykey integer not null primary key, mycolumn varchar) "
val jdbcConnString = "jdbc:hostname:2181/hbase-unsecure"
val user="USER"
val pass="PASS"
var connection:Connection = null
Class.forName(driver)
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnString, user, pass)
val statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.executeUpdate(ddlCode)
```